# Customize sorting in criteria

Tags: grails, criteria

I found grails criteria and want to customize sorting options.

E.g. I have domain **Book** and I want to make some criteria:

```
Book.createCriteria().list {
    //some code like ilike('name', 'book')
    ...

    order(params.sort, params.order)
}
```

I want to make specific sorting rule, e.g. by `name.trim()`.

How can I do this?

Comment: The two arguments for `order` are `fieldName` and sorting `direction`, what do you mean by making specific sorting rule? If pagination is not important you can always roll your own sorting function and order the result set in memory.

Comment: @Alidad, pagination is important, I wouldn't load all the objects from database (in my case it's about 10,000) and select 50 after that. Specific sorting is something like `select * from table where order by trim('name');` but in hibernate criteria, is it possible?

Comment: An alternative could be using hql directly. `Book.executeQuery("select bk from Book bk order by trim(name)")`

Comment: @Alidad, I'm not sure, it's valid hql expression. Is `trim` function acceptable in hql?

Comment: H2 accepts it, it depends on your underlying database. I found another solution using createCriteria, I will post it momentarily. But when it comes to passing functions it relies on your database to support that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a solution provided [here](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/), by extending the hirbernate `Order` class, you can customize it to accept functions and use it with createCriteria. 
I wont be surprised, if there is a nicer and easier approach since this source is pretty old and also Grails is cooler than this :D

First you need a class extending Hibernate Order:

Originally by:[spostelnicu](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/)

```
public class OrderBySqlFormula extends Order {
    private String sqlFormula;

    protected OrderBySqlFormula(String sqlFormula) {
        super(sqlFormula, true);
        this.sqlFormula = sqlFormula;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sqlFormula;
    }

    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        return sqlFormula;
    }

    public static Order sqlFormula(String sqlFormula) {
       return new OrderBySqlFormula(sqlFormula);
   }


}
```

Then you can pass instance of this class to your createCriteria:

```
def ls = Domain.createCriteria().list {
       order OrderBySqlFormula.sqlFormula("TRIM(name)")
}
```

Note1: You can pass any formula to sqlFormula as long as the underlying database accepts it.

Note2: Using such approach might cause migration challenges.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for nice answer, I use mysql and I'm not sure, `trim` function is exists

Comment: Did you try `"name.TRIM()"` what you pass in formula is up to you and the underlying database.